# Does Spring Data PagingAndSortingRepository for JPA objects work for composite primary keys

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I’m just getting started with Spring Data. Will a PagingAndSortingRepository with an underlying JpaRepository work with a JPA object that has a composite primary key using an EmbeddedId object?

I’m asking about the built in support in Spring, as I know I could implement the interface manually if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying repository will work, yes, but if you want to control the order of the properties in the `@EmbeddedId` with respect to the order by clause you will need to explicitly set them in the Sort/Pageable object.